# Select upvote button on reddit with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to send click to a reddit upvote button using the selenium in python but I am unable to select the upvote button "arrow up login-required access-required"

HTML Code of upvote and downvote buttons :

```html
<div class="arrow up login-required access-required" data-event-action="upvote" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>
<div class="score likes">•</div>
<div class="score unvoted">•</div>
<div class="score dislikes">•</div>
<div class="arrow down login-required access-required" data-event-action="downvote" role="button" aria-label="downvote" tabindex="0"></div>
```

The code I tried was

```html
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='upvote'")
target.click()
```

```html
target = driver.find_element_by_class_name('midcol unvoted')
target.click()
```

But none of them appear to work.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to click `<div class="arrow up login-required access-required" data-event-action="upvote" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>` but both of the selectors you provided look unrelated. Your xpath try indicates a button (you want a div) and your 'by class name' try doesn't refer to anything in your example.

This should work fine for the example you provided:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.arrow.up").click
```

However, many pages on reddit have multiple upvote arrows, so you may need to make your selector more specific to work on the actual webpage.